Controlling multiple solenoids simultaneously with no microcontroller
I have a project that requires simultaneous functioning of four solenoid valves. Ideally, these should be controlled using push button switches, and I would like to be able to control them together and individually as below:

Button 1: Activates Solenoid 1,
Button 2: Activates Solenoid 2,
Button 3: Activates Solenoid 3,
Button 4: Activates Solenoid 1 + 4,
Button 5: Activates Solenoid 2 + 4,
Button 6: Activates Solenoid 3 + 4

I have managed to achieve this using an Arduino, but I have been tasked with eliminating microcontrollers + software requirements from the device. Would anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?
To add another layer of difficulty, I would like to be able to press two buttons simultaneously (i.e buttons 4 + 5) and still actuate the relevant solenoids.
The solenoids are 24V (DC) - 3W Normally Closed solenoids and I have a 24V (DC) 3.0A power supply which can be used for this purpose.
I would appreciate any help you may be able to provide.

24V 3.0A power supply ... AC or DC? ... please edit your question ... do not write a comment

How does your Arduino code handle it in logic? Why not implement the same logic without code with logic gates? What items can you use as logic gates?

Currently its handled using if statements, i.e if button 1 + 2 are pressed then the relevant solenoids are activated. Would you be able to explain how logic gates could be used in this case?



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Addition of diodes allows use of single-pole pushbuttons or switches while preventing backfeeds.
Something like 1N4001, rated for 1.0 A, would be suitable and easily available.

Thats just what I was looking for, thanks for the help its much appreciated!

Dual pole switches are a thing,
That is that is use a button that operates two sets of contacts.
These are available from mechanical engineering suppliers etc.
Sticker shock is also a thing engineering supplies will not be competitive with Arduino on price even against recommended retail price of genuine Arduino.  but for that money you get reliability.
So for button 4 one set of contacts goes in parallel with button 1 to operate solenoid 1 and the other set operate solenoid 4. etc...
That's a solution, here's a cheaper alternative, perhaps you are already committed to using a certain style of buttons that are unsuitable to control the solenoids directly, in that case you
could use those buttons to control the relays you already have.
Buttons 4,5  and 6 will need to have diodes between them and the relay inputs so that relay 3 can't back-feed to relay 4 through the button 4 wiring when button 1 is presses  etc.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

As you said I am limited on the type of buttons unfortunately, I think diodes might be the answer I am looking for in this case. Just so I'm clear, output from button 4 would need a diode going to relay 1, so that when button 1 is pressed it won't backfeed relays 1 and 4?

it would need two dioes one to each relay,  one to prevent the relay1 signal from from backfeeding relay4 and another to prevent the relay4 signal from backfeeding to relay 1.

You should be able to do this with a diode matrix. Basically each button switches power or ground to the solenoids through diodes, for switches that activate more than one solenoid there are diodes going from that switch to each one. The diodes allow a switch to activate multiple solenoids without feeding back into ones that aren't supposed to be activated.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this example, SW1 activates solenoid L1, SW2 activates L2, and SW3 activates both L3 and L1.
Diode D4 keeps SW1 from activating L3. D5-D7 are for spike suppression, maybe not needed with just switches but if you use transistor drivers you would need them.
You can get away with fewer diodes, D2 for instance could be eliminated as no other switches control L2.
This shows plain push-button switches, they would have to be rated to handle the solenoids. Alternatively low current switches could be used with transistors to drive the solenoids with a similar diode switching arrangement.
If your solenoids are AC instead of DC you would need to get a bit more creative, maybe using the buttons and diodes to switch DC relays that would then switch AC to the solenoids.

Brilliant thank you for the help!

Maybe I'm missing something, but the solution seems trivial.

Wire button 1 straight to solenoid 1.

Wire button 2 straight to solenoid 2.

Wire button 3 straight to solenoid 3.

Wire button 4, through diodes, to solenoids 1 and 4 (i.e. two diodes, one diode feeding each solenoid).

Wire button 5, through diodes, to solenoids 2 and 4.

Wire button 6, through diodes, to solenoids 3 and 4.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
